# How do I read a large file gradually?

Tags: java, large-files

I'm having some problems reading a file with java. It is absolutely huge (2,5G) and adjusting my memory doesn't help. The data is all on a single line so I can't read it one line at a time. What I would like to do is to read the file until I find a certain string for example "<|start|>" or "<|end|>" and then print the data in between these strings so the memory is cleared and I can continue reading the rest of the file. So what I basically am looking for is a type of reader that starts reading at a certain start string and stops reading at a stop string. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9):

You need to open up a `Reader` (e.g. a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader` wrapping a `FileInputStream`) and read chunks at a time with `read(char[], int, int)` or `read(char[])`. It's up to you to take care of finding the token - including in the case where it starts in one chunk and ends on another. Also be aware that `read()` may not fill the buffer; you need to use the return value to see how much data it's actually written to the array.

Comment: I get distracted for one second and Jon Skeet steals my glory :(

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look to see if [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is suitable for your data. You can use the [useDelimiter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)) method to change the patterns it uses to tokenize the input.

Answer (score -1):

Try this pseudo code:

```
 char [] start = {'<','|','s','t','a','r','t','|','>' };

 char [] start = {'<','|','e','n','d','|','>' };

 char [] buff  = new char[9];

 while( true ) {
     char c = readChar();
     if( c  == '<' ) {
         buff = readChars( 9 ) ; 
         if( buff == start ) {
             inside = true ;
             skip( 9 ); // start
         } else if( buff == end )  {
             inside = false;
             skip(7); // end 
         }
      } 
      if( inside ) {
          print( char ) ;
      }
 }
```

The idea is to read until you find the token and raise a flag, when the flag is on you print the value, if you find the end token you shutdown the flag.

There should be a number of ways to code the previous pseudo-code.  I'll update this answer later.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach: you may broke the string between the reads of the file.

Like: on one buffer you may store something like "blabla<|st" and on the other "art|>"

So it really won't work

Comment: @Kico Lobo: I don't understand the problem (given < doesn't appear elsewhere in the string)...

Comment: Well, actually..it does appear elsewhere in the string

Comment: @Kico Lobo. That's why I wrote ( `readChars( 9 )`  ) and I said: *pseudocode* because how do you read 9 chars is not described here.